# Unusual Vertices issue with rigging a low-poly model?

Tags: rigging, vertices

I've been following a tutorial on how to rig a really basic PS1/Resident Evil-like model. Things have been going fine up until I had assigned the torso vertex group.
[image]

I've checked the weight paints and for any loose vertices to the best of my ability but I'm still unsure as to what's going on?

Here's the tutorial that I've been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0YOZHvGPR8

Comment: Hello, as Spood says, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you have vertices that are unassigned to a vertex group.

To verify this is the case, in edit mode with your mesh selected, first ensure no vertices are selected with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then go to your vertex group and with the torso Vertex Group selected press the Select button:

[image: vertex group options]

This will select all vertices that are in this group that have weights. You should notice the offending vertex will not be selected. To resolve it, select the vertex and press assign, and it will put that vertex into the Torso group with 1.0 Weight.

If this isn't the issue, feel free to share a .blend file and it will be easier to determine the root cause.